# How to cast a unsigned int to a pointer and dereference it?

Tags: c, casting, dereference

I'm trying something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x = 701;
    unsigned int p = (unsigned int) &x;

    printf("Original ptr: %u\n", p);
    printf("Dereferencing ptr: %u\n", *(int *) p);
}
```

but get **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** while dereferencing `p`, does any know how to cast an `unsigned int` to a pointer and dereferencing it?

I'm using **gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)**.

Comment: Is it a 64 bit system?`

Comment: Here `unsigned int p` type of `p` shall be pointer type if you want to dereference it. Change it to `unsigned int *p`

Comment: @Devolus yes, I'm using 64 bit system

Comment: @Achal I save it as an `unsigned int` for some reasons, read more for: https://arjunsreedharan.org/post/105266490272/hide-data-inside-pointers

Comment: `int` is 4 bytes, `int *`is 8 bytes. You can't cast an int to an 64 bit pointer and expect it to work, unless in some rare cases when you know you want to deal with the hardware. It invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Devolus You're right, when I test it on x86, it works!!! Thank you so much!!!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting between `int` and pointer types comes with implementation-defined aspects. The integer type might be too small to contain a pointer or vice versa.

Therefore the integer type `uintptr_t` (stdint.h) was invented. This is a type guaranteed to be large enough to hold a converted pointer value for the specific system, portably. So you should switch `unsigned int` with `uintptr_t` (which unlike `unsigned long long` etc is a portable type)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x = 701;
    uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t) &x;

    printf("Original ptr: %" PRIuPTR "\n", p);
    printf("Dereferencing ptr: %u\n", *(unsigned int*)p);
}
```

(Printing a `uintptr_t` with printf portably requires this weird-looking macro `PRIuPTR` from inttypes.h. This one expands to something like `"llu"`.)

Answer (score 1):

This will fail on 64 bit systems, because a pointer is 8 bytes long, but an int is only 4 bytes long. This means that you are losing the last four bytes of data in the cast, creating an invalid pointer.

This is how your code should look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x = 701;
    unsigned int *p = &x;

    printf("Original ptr: %u\n", p);
    printf("Dereferencing ptr: %u\n", *p);
}
```

And if you insist on casting to integers, then this could be a possible solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x = 701;
    unsigned long long p = (unsigned long long) &x;

    printf("Original ptr: %u\n", p);
    printf("Dereferencing ptr: %u\n", *(int *) p);
}
```

Note: you should really just be using standard pointers. The size of a `long long` **is not guaranteed** by the C compiler, and this code lacks readability.

Comment: It works when I change to use `unsigned long long`. Thank you  for point that out!

Comment: "The size of a long long is not guaranteed by the C compiler"  So use `uintptr_t` instead, which is the correct type and guaranteed to work.

Comment: sorry, I have to give @lundin this point, he (or she) just reminds me [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models)